# Wordpress JSON plugin returning blank array for categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this [link http://isbeingbuilt.com/ll/?json=get_category_index](http://isbeingbuilt.com/ll/?json=get_category_index)

link to get all categories. But it is returning blank array:

```
{"status":"ok","count":0,"categories":[]}
```

Can someone tell me why it is not returning all categories. Although there are many categories in wordpress website. Please check this link:

http://isbeingbuilt.com/ll

Comment: post your source code problem please

Comment: Which source code? I am using WordPress JSON plugin. Please check http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

Answer (score 0):

Looking around a bit, I don't think your blog is using standard WordPress categories. Have a look at http://isbeingbuilt.com/ll/?p=1&json=1 or http://isbeingbuilt.com/ll/?p=13&json=1. `categories` is blank but `"taxonomy_deal-categories` has a lot of action!

Out of the box, the json-api plugin doesn't provide a way to do what you're asking but, luckily, [Stack Overflow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18200/44795) is [pretty amazing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/28583/44795).